# Converting JSF Managed beans to CDI Beans

Tags: jsf, cdi

A JSF project needs to be converted to a CDI beans project. There are few issues to solve.

1. What should we use when replacing @ViewScope
2. How can we replace @ManagedProperty
3. Will @EJB will work as previous in CDIs
4. Any changes needed in configuration files except beans.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'm assuming you're on JSF 2.0 or 2.1, in which case you can use MyFaces CODI, or Seam 3, or Omnifaces for `@ViewScoped`. For JSF 2.2 it's there out of the box.
2. `@ManagedProperty` becomes `@Inject`.
3. Yes.
4. No.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear. I converted it successfully. Had to remove Final in class definition.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason you had to remove `final` is because CDI creates proxies.